# How to drop a foreign key in doctrine 2 migrations

Tags: php, migration, doctrine, doctrine-orm

I want to drop a foreign key in a doctrine 2 migration.
But there is no dropForeignKeyConstraint()

Does anybody know how to drop it?

Answer (score 4):

```
public function down(Schema $schema)
{
    $table = $schema->getTable('table_name');
    $table->removeForeignKey('foreign_key_name');
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Here it is:

```
public function down()
{
    $this->dropForeignKey('table_name', 'email_foreign_key');
}
```

http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/1.2/docs/manual/migrations/en