# doctrine - update columns with fk

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony-2.7

I have 2 tables (let's call them A (`id`, `some_other_columns`) and B (`a_id`, `some_other_columns`)). Obviously `a_id` from B points to `id` from A (and has a fk on it). All is fine. Now... problem is that by mistake when tables were made the id was set to signed. I want to fix that and make it unsigned (but it may as well been any other change that affects the column definition).

If you make that from queries you deactivate fks/delete that fk, make the change, activate back/add fk back.

I need to do that from doctrine:schema:update (because is run automatically on server deployment bla bla -> lets say because procedure).

I made the specific changes to entities:

```
A: 
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", options={"unsigned"=true})
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
*/
private $id;




 * @ORM\Table(name="B", uniqueConstraints={@ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="a_b", columns={"aEntity"})})
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 B:
   /**
    * @var aEntity
    *
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="CoreBundle\Entity\A", inversedBy="bEntity")
    * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="a_id", referencedColumnName="id")
   */
   private $aEntity;
```

The generated code looks correct:

```
 $php app/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql
 ALTER TABLE A CHANGE id id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL;
 ALTER TABLE B CHANGE a_id a_id INT UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL;
```

But... of course I get an error (since fk is constraining the column definitions and is not disabled).

```
 An exception occurred while executing 'ALTER TABLE A CHANGE id id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL':                                          
 SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1833 Cannot change column 'id': used in a foreign key constraint 'FK_3041AF5B7975B7E7' of table 'db_name.a'
```

How can I update the tables using doctrine schema update (maybe it has a flag or something? Personally I can't find any.)?

Comment: Have you seen this SO question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3643344/how-to-drop-a-foreign-key-in-doctrine-2-migrations

Comment: No... I checked it now but I don't understand how I can use it. Can you explain pls.? (from what I see it refers to a db migration - I'm not using a migration, I am using the entity annotations to update the schema; sidenote... I never used migrations before but from what I see here: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine1/en/latest/en/manual/migrations.html it doesn't refere the entities, it's manually updating things -> I admit I may be wrong in my asumption and if so pls. point out where :) ).

Comment: I don't think you can do this through annotations alone.